# How to set images to a List view using custom adapter from array list by using glide*

Tags: android, xml, listview, kotlin, android-glide

I have put all the images in a drawable and created an array list, how to 
     retrieve those images in list view using the custom adapter.

---

**This is an array list of images**

```
Strings.xml 
  <string-array name="images">
    <item>@drawable/cash</item>
    <item>@drawable/paytm</item>
    <item>@drawable/phonepe</item>
    <item>@drawable/googlepay</item>
   </string-array>
```

---

**This is the kotlin code**

```
       var myadapter = object : BaseAdapter() {
       override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: 
                              ViewGroup?): View 
     { 
       val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this@MainActivity)
       val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.indview, null)           
  Glide.with(this@MainActivity).load(R.drawable.cash).into(v.iview)
  Glide.with(this@MainActivity).load(R.drawable.paytm).into(v.iview)
  Glide.with(this@MainActivity).load(R.drawable.phonepe).into(v.iview)
  Glide.with(this@MainActivity).load(R.drawable.googlepay).into(v.iview)
     return v
        }
```

---

I expect the list view should get the images by entering the names 
attribute in load() in Glide

Comment: I suggest you to use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead of ListView

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a normal Array of Integer, then pass this array to the lazy-loading Adapter(adapter with holder) and call `Glide` like this:

```
Glide.with(activity).load(resources.get(position)).into(v.iview)
```